# How long will FindElements wait?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Say the implicit timeout is 10 sec.
Then I execute an FindElements (plural!) with some XPath.

**Question**

How long FindElements waits, until deciding to return? *(please disregard any deferred execution feature of any language. Then I rephrase my question to FindElements(...).Count())*

**Reasoning the question**

I suppose in case there is no match then it will wait for 10 secs.
However if there is at least one match, then will it return instantly? This case we will miss a possible following elements if they populated by the page's javascript during the 10 sec.

My general problem is the following:

- We do not want to wait for the timeout *unconditionally* all the time(it would be bad#1)
- We do not want to miss any match what is available within the timeout (it would be bad #2

**Question rephrased**

Which bad (#1 or #2) is the reality, regarding FindElements behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a  minimum number of elements that will suffice, so you can go ahead? If so you can ditch the implicit wait and go for an ExpectedCondition -> https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.Integer-

Comment: ExpectedConditions was deprecated a few years ago and is no longer present in JavaScript/node.js versions of Selenium Webdriver 4.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is affected by the `'implicit wait'` times in force at the time of execution. When implicitly waiting, this method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

What you could do, so that you do not miss any matches is to wait for the page to completely load by checking the [document.readyState](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp) to be equal to complete and then call the `driver.findElements` method.

```
public void waitForPageLoaded() {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
                ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
                    }
                };
```

Comment: I've played with document.readyState. Unfortunatelly it can not be used when dynamic page loads and fills a table with ajax (always 'complete' in my experience.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about the WebElements in question and the web development framework used for the app? There surely must be some visual indicator on the page for the end user to know that the loading of the page has completed. Try having an explicit wait on such elements instead

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this workaround because ExpectedConditions is deprecated and no longer available in JavaScript/node.js versions of Selenium 4.x. This only works if the elements you want to wait for are all children of the same parent. The hack is to use the CSS nth-child selector to ensure that you have at least n elements present:

```
return driver.wait(
    until.elementIsVisible(
        driver.wait(
            until.elementLocated(By.css("ul.parent > li:nth-child(5)")), 
            10 * 1000)), // wait up to 10s for the presence of at least 5 matching child elements
    1 * 1000) => () {
    
    // now you can grab the elements and act on them.
}
```